# Why pandas df reindexing is ignored?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have the following custom function. All works fine but the reindexing and reset index ignored for some reason. This function is going into a loop where these transformations applied to a few data frames. The aim is to return transformed_df as output of all transformations applied to df.

```
def apply_transformation(df):
    # Apply transformation to all dataframes
    #rename columns
    df.rename(columns={"date" : "Date", "Wrong_name": "Correct_name"}, inplace=True)
    #reverse the df - THIS IS IGNORED
    df.reindex(index=df.index[::-1])
    #ignored
    df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
    #It is working
    df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
    #working too
    transformed_df = df.drop(['areaCode', 'areaName', 'areaType', 'Date'], axis=1, inplace=True)
    # Return the transformed dataframe
    return transformed_df
```

What is wrong?
(edited for clarification)

Comment: Is the format you post just an error in copy paste or have you really no indentation?

Comment: `df.reindex` is not an in-place operation, you want `df=df.reindex(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Reindexing does not happen in-place.  You need to assign it to a variable

Change:

```
    df.reindex(index=df.index[::-1])
```

to this:

```
    df = df.reindex(index=df.index[::-1])
```

Comment: This will also reverse the order of the rows which may or may not be what the OP intends. If not then `df.index = df.index[::-1]` reverses the index only and leaves the rows as-is.

Comment: Yes, I intend to reverse the rows completely, the oldest data to be in the front, and the latest on the end. It is a time series data.

Comment: If I use df = df.reindex(index=df.index[::-1]) that breaks transformed_df = df.drop(['areaCode', 'areaName', 'areaType', 'Date'], axis=1, inplace=True)